# <a4j:commandButton> not invoking the action

Tags: ajax, jsf, richfaces, jsf-1.2

I'm trying to call a simple action method in a bean using `<a4j:commandButton>`. But when I used `rendered` or `disabled` attributes (also evaluating from an action method) it's not working.

Here's my code snippet:

```
<a4j:region block="true" >
    <a4j:form id="download_form">
        <a4j:commandButton id="download_button"
          action="#{studentInfo.actionDownload}"
          onclick="#{rich:component('download_progress')}.show(); setPopupPosition('#{rich:clientId('download_progress')}');"
          reRender="dlod_msg_grd"
          oncomplete="#{rich:component('download_progress')}.hide();
          value="Download a student" 
          rendered="#{studentInfo.validForDownload}"
          />
    </a4j:form>
</a4j:region>
```

If I use `rendered="#{studentInfo.validForDownload}"` as `rendered="#{true}"` it all works fine, the bean's action method got invoked. But the way I used now doesn't work

The `studentInfo.validForDownload` is evaluating to to true thus the `a4j:commandButton` is rendering properly.

Comment: What's the scope of your `studentInfo` managed bean?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, it's in Request scope

Comment: Looks like your `studentInfo.validForDownload` field has the default value which is `false`. Try adding the `@KeepAlive` annotation on the `studentInfo` class definition e.g. `@KeepAlive public class StudentIfo { ... }`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, Tried that too but no luck

Comment: Try to use a `<h:messages>` and to remove the ajax behavior in order that your page could do a refresh and show other problems like conversion problems or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `studentInfo` managed bean is of request scope, as said in your response to Luiggi, the `rendered="#{studentInfo.validForDownload}"` will always evaluate to default value. And as mentioned by Luiggi, you have to use `a4j:keepAlive` in order to get the desired behaviour, but with a little change in your code:

```
<a4j:keepAlive beanName = "studentInfo"/>
<h:form id="download_form">  
  <a4j:region block="true" >
    <a4j:commandButton id="download_button"
      action="#{studentInfo.actionDownload}"
      onclick="#{rich:component('download_progress')}.show(); setPopupPosition('#{rich:clientId('download_progress')}');"
      reRender="dlod_msg_grd"
      oncomplete="#{rich:component('download_progress')}.hide();
      value="Download a student" 
      rendered="#{studentInfo.validForDownload}"/>
  </a4j:region>
</h:form>
```

I don't know if the `a4j:form` has an effect but for sure `h:form` will work

Comment: Tried that one but getting this error. <a4j:keepAlive beanName="#{studentInfo}"> Must be literal

Comment: Ah, I am so sorry, please try: <a4j:keepAlive beanName="studentInfo">

Comment: That also didn't work. Getting an NotSerializable exception. Is there a way that I can keep out the value being setting to default.

Comment: Yes I did and now getting a - Caused by: javax.el.ELException: Cannot convert StudentInformationBackingBean@5db2381b of type class $Proxy119 to class StudentInformationBackingBean

Comment: do you have any not serializable member in you bean ? if yes, then try to make them serializable or just mark them as `transient`

Comment: All members in the bean are serializable most of them are Strings and for object types I just put transient just to make sure. But still no luck getting the same error.

Comment: I think this should be in another question where you put your managed bean code, so people can help you. For the solution to your initial question, you can try mine with simple String objects.

Comment: @LaabidiRaissi in order to avoid the usage of `<a4j:keepAlive>` you can use it as annotation on the managed bean in form of `@KeepAlive`. I suggested this in comment to prevent an answer like yours. Since OP said this doesn't solve the problem, I didn't want to go further since OP could have other problems not shown in the code posted on the question...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, please notice, my message "And as mentioned by Luiggi, you have to use a4j:keepAlive in order to get the desired behaviour, but with a little change in your code:". And I gave an answer, just to show code modification. And in by "as Luiggi said" I think, this means I agree with you (about using keepalive) and I suugested changes in code. Thanks

Comment: I gave up trying, used session attributes to store the member variables and retrieved from validForDownload for validity.